# Get all the src (or SRC) URLs Java

Tags: java, url, arrays, web-crawler

I am trying to get all the src (or SRC) URLs that appear in an array of bytes, however, I do not know how to implement the byte array. The code I have now extracts all parts of the HTML that begin with src= or SRC= and pulls out the correct items. However, how would the byte array play a role in this? The byte array is a sequence of chars that might contain src (or SRC) URLs, initialized from the contents of a URL. Furthermore, the string of vectors that is at the end of this function is supposed to contain all the src attributes found in data. I have a saveResource function that saves a resource in a file, as well as in a byte array which is also shown below.

How do I store the src urls that my program is pulling out into the byte array?

Comment: What do you mean by "implement the byte array"? When you ask "how would the byte array play a role in this?" what byte array are you referring to? You answer the question yourself in the next sentence. When you ask "How do I store the src urls that my program is pulling out into the byte array?" what byte array are you referring to?

Comment: @guest I am referring to the byte[] data that is included in the function name public static Vector<String> getSourceUrls(byte[] data). My task is to store the src urls into this byte array, but I do not know how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're asking how to store a `Vector<String>` in a byte array. This sounds weird, so maybe I've interpreted it wrong.

- `Vector`s are serializable. You can use an `ObjectOutputStream` to write them to an output stream.
- `ByteArrayOutputStream` implements an `OutputStream` that writes to memory. It has a method `toByteArray()` that you can call to get its contents as a byte array.

That should be enough to solve this problem.

edit: maybe also some `System.arraycopy` if you need it to go in the `data` argument... again, weird.